# RegularExpressionValidator and JQuery Dialog crashing on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

**In the beginning, there was no Validator and all was working fine**

A Web User Control have a button that opens a Panel in a Jquery PopUp Dialog. That Panel have some TextBoxes.

**Then it came the RegularExpressionValidator and I'm pissed off**

I added RegEx Validators to my multiline textboxes in order to ensure a max length. They do work, but when I close the JQuery Dialog and try openning it again, an error raises: "Cannot read property value of null". Here is way:

When dialog is closed:

```
$("#" + PanelClientId)        
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,            
            hide: tipoHide,
            modal: true,
            title: titulo,
            width: ancho,
            height: alto,
            close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove();}
            });
```

the Validator control is null but the client validation routine triggers and fail on

```
function ValidatorGetValue(id) {
    var control;
    control = document.getElementById(id);
    if (typeof(control.value) == "string")
```

because control is null, as I said.

**Please help me**

I hope I made myself clear with my poor english. Please help me to solve this. I'm thinking about adding client side events prior to the validation and there, assign the ControlToValidate to my validators, but till now I haven't been able to add any event that executes before the validation.

**So family,** thanks a lot for your time reading this and for your valuable help.

Here is my validator code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtJustificacionSpeaker" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true"
    Rows="4" Width="90%" CssClass="TextoMultilineaScrollAuto"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revJustificacionSpeaker" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="La justificación no puede exceder 2000 caracteres" ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,2000})$" ControlToValidate="txtJustificacionSpeaker" />
```

Comment: I just deleted all Regex Validators on that control and implemented normal server validation; now its working again.

Comment: In fact, I had to replace all validators with server side code in every place where the control to validate could be displayed on a JQuery UI dialog. I'll let the question open, mayvbe someone is able to solve it without removing the validators.